# android:state_selected not working

Tags: android, xml, selector

I just want to change the image on button click using the selector in the XML file. `android:state_pressed="true"` is working while `android:state_selected="true"` not working.
Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/discount1"/>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/discount1"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/discount2"/>
</selector>
```

Here is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.democoordinatorlayout.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check your code. The first two items in your selector have the same drawable specified. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: I have changed the drawable file still state_selected is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `buttonselector` to this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@drawable/discount1" /> <!-- pressed state -->

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/login" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

**EDIT**

To change image of button permanently, use the following code.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/your_image1"/>
```

Then in java file, add this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
               btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I want the button image to be changed permanently. state_pressed will change the image until the button is pressed and when you release, it will be on its default image which is not my target.

Comment: I don't want to do it programatically. If it is not possible without java code, then what does state_selected do?

Comment: The `state_selected` is used when an item is selected using a keyboard/dpad/trackball/etc. Read the [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) Doc by Android. What is the issue with programmatically? It works perfectly. The `state_pressed` is a transient code which goes away when the button is released.

Comment: Now I got the difference. I was misunderstanding state_selected. Thank you so much.. ...

Comment: If the answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the tick icon next to the answer.